# Batch file exiting when trying to check if file exists, unknown issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a simple batch file to install a few commonly used applications. I want to check if it is already installed and then try to run an installer if not. Here is part of the code, it fails when checking IF EXIST... This code is in another IF EXIST loop that also fails.. If I put the code in one line it works but not as a block. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
Echo "Installing Bitcentral Core, Please wait..."
"%~dp0installers\BitCentral\0.9.6\BC Software\bitcentral_setup_0.9.6_64.exe" /S /some-other-flags

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Bitcentral Core\bitcentral.exe"(
    echo "Bitcentral Core Install Complete" 
)ELSE(
    echo "Error installing BitCentral"
)
```

Comment: You need a spaces before the parantheses. The syntax is clearly shown in the help file for the `IF` command.

Comment: True, but I don't think the need for spacing is that obvious.. Thanks though.

Comment: `IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Bitcentral Core\bitcentral.exe"(` should be `IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Bitcentral Core\bitcentral.exe" (` and `)ELSE(` should be `)ELSE (` or `) ELSE (`.

Comment: @nick you must be using some weird font then.  When I look at the `IF exist` example in the help file it clearly shows the spaces plain as day.

Comment: @Squashman I see the spaces, but usually something like the number of spaces between expressions like IF/ELSE, new lines, spaces/tabs are a stylistic choice.. So just cause the example shows a space around IF/ELSE it's not really intuitive that is how it must be/that a space is the issue..

Answer (score 2):

You need to have spaces before/after the parenthesis:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Bitcentral Core\bitcentral.exe" (
    echo "Bitcentral Core Install Complete" 
) ELSE (
    echo "Error installing BitCentral"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, a bit silly! Surprised I never ran into that before..

Comment: Hi @dcp, this is a new `batch-file` answer from an old member. No problem, just surprised to read a Batch reply from a member with a very large rep, but I hadn't read anything about it before... Welcome! **`;)`**